# Как создать сервис soap на django?

Tags: python, django

Как создать сервис soap на django?

Answer (score 1):

[Обзор на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206154/whats-the-best-soap-client-library-for-python-and-where-is-the-documentation-fo/206964#206964)

Лично я использовал SUDS, примеры см. в документации.
SOAPPy, который описывают в Dive Into Python, крайне не советую.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте soaplib (+ еще есть куча аналогов). В рунете полно описаний, в т.ч. и интеграция с Django.

Comment: а если уже имеется soap сервис на .net - то как можно обратиться с django  к нему? можно пример

Comment: SOAP - это протокол. Не важно, на чем написана конкретный сервис.